# Can I achieve addition of Integers and concatenation of Strings in a single generic method?

Tags: java, string, generics, integer

I'm learning Generics.I have written the following code just for practice. In this code I've created a single generic method for addition of two number and concatenation of two Strings as per values provided by the method call, it should be add the Integer or concatenate Strings.

```
class Kaushal28{

public <T> void  add(T a, T b){

  //System.out.println(a+b);

}    
}
public class NewClass59 {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Kaushal28 k = new Kaushal28();
        k.add(5, 8);
        k.add("5","8");
}
}
```

I'm not sure whether this can be done in a single method or not. If not then what can be the solution of this problem? Can I achieve this by use of generic class?

Comment: No. The `+` operator only works as mathematical addition and string concatenation. It only knows about numeric types and the String type. It doesn't know about an unbounded `T`.

Comment: then what can I do for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have this as a generic *method*, but you can have a generic [*strategy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```
interface Adder<T> { T add(T a, T b); }
```

and then specialize it for String and Integer:

```
class StringAdder implements Adder<String> {
  @Override public String add(String a, String b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

class IntegerAdder implements Adder<Integer> {
  @Override public Integer add(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

You could then use this in a "single generic method" like this:

```
<T> void something(Adder<T> adder, T a, T b) {
  System.out.println(adder.add(a, b));
}

something(new StringAdder(), "Hello", "World");
something(new IntegerAdder(), 1, 2);
```

or, of course:

```
System.out.println(new StringAdder().add("Hello", "World"));
System.out.println(new IntegerAdder().add(1, 2));
```

Comment: of course we can use `(1+2)` but I was trying to implement generics.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to have a generic method that covers every types so you will need to overload the method to support the target types, but here is a potential start that covers all `Numbers` and `CharSequence`:

```
class Kaushal28 {

    public Number add(Number a, Number b){
        return a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
    }

    public CharSequence add(CharSequence a, CharSequence b){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length() + b.length());
        return sb.append(a).append(b).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first method doesn't need to use generics. Replacing `T` with `Number` would be equivalent (provided you don't use an explicit generic constraint).

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto that means overloading is must in two different types like string and Integer?

Comment: @AndyTurner that's correct, I wanted to ensure that we had the same type for both parameters but with a return type Number it doesn't make any sense indeed

Comment: @Kaushal28 I'm not sure I understand your question, could you please reformulate?

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto You answered simple overloading which I already know. My question is can we achieve this in a single generic method or not?

Comment: @Kaushal28 "No it is not possible to have a generic method"

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Kaushal28<T> {    
        public T add(T a, T b){
           dynamic a1 = a;
           dynamic b1 = b;
            return a1+b1;
        }
      }
        
    public class NewClass59 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Kaushal28<int> ob =new Kaushal28<int>();
            Console.WriteLine(ob.add(5,2));
           
            Kaushal28<string> obj =new Kaushal28<string>();
            Console.WriteLine(obj.add("5","2"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: as a general rule of thumb, please do add some explanation with it.